# Multiple css files Child theme wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

I hope your greate, i have some issues with loading separate files based on url variable in wordpress. I thought it would be best to do this in the child theme functions file. code below:

```
$getURLVar = explode("/",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

if($getURLVar[1] == "temp"){
   $uri_based_style = 'style-temp.css'; 
} else {
   $uri_based_style = 'style.css';  
}


 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles',999 );
 function theme_enqueue_styles() {
 wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
 wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . $uri_based_style,
  array( $parent_style )
 );
}
```

I cant get it to load the file.
Both css files are based in the child theme dir.
Does anybody have a clue ?

Best Regards

Comment: If you're referencing `$uri_based_style` in a function (but defining it elsewhere), you might have to declare it as `global` a the top of the function.  See http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is the variable **scope**.  You've defined the variable *outside* of the function, so it's not available by default inside the function.  For simplicity sake, just declare it *inside* the function, like so:

```
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    $getURLVar = explode("/",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    if($getURLVar[1] == "temp"){
       $uri_based_style = 'style-temp.css'; 
    } else {
       $uri_based_style = 'style.css';  
    }

    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . $uri_based_style,
        array( $parent_style )
    );
}
```

### Alternatively...

If for some reason you really want / need to declare it outside the function, use `global`, like so:

```
$getURLVar = explode("/",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
if($getURLVar[1] == "temp"){
   $uri_based_style = 'style-temp.css'; 
} else {
   $uri_based_style = 'style.css';  
}

function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    // global in the variable here so you can use it in the function
    global $uri_based_style;  

    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . $uri_based_style,
        array( $parent_style )
    );
}
```